# Personalize the Google Maps badge

Tags: css, google-maps, badge

I would like to personalize the position badge on a Google Map (with API). I know it's possible to change the appeareance of the badge with CSS or image. But how I can do that ?

This is what I want : [image]

The small rectangle is the normal view, and the big rectangle is the clicked view (with informations). Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'big rectangle' and 'small rectangle' are both infowindows.  Styling infowindows has been asked here before:
[Styling Google Maps InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634991/styling-google-maps-infowindow)

You'd need to have an event listener, so initially the small infowindows are all displayed on load.  Then when you click on a point or on an infowindow, you then show the large infowindow.