# Change infowindows with infobox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, infowindow, infobox

Is there any way to change infowindow with infoboxes becouse I need more styling than basic infowindows...

CODE AND DEMO: http://jsbin.com/EVEWOta/26

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
        service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var contentStr = '<h5>'+place.name+'</h5><p>'+place.formatted_address;
            if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<br>'+place.formatted_phone_number;
            if (!!place.website) contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="'+place.website+'">'+place.website+'</a>';
            contentStr += '<br>'+place.types+'</p>';
            if (!!place.photos) contentStr += '<img src=' + place.photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 300, 'maxHeight': 300 }) + '></img>';
            infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
          } else { 
            var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status="+status+"</h5>";
            infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
          }
        });

    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
```

InfoWindows can't style as I want so I need to change it with infoboxes, but how???

Comment: Yes, write the code. See: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good tool for styling infowindows: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html

And some more resources at this answer: [Styling Google Maps InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634991/styling-google-maps-infowindow/5635846#5635846)

Update:
To put an infobubble on your map you can implement it like this, with whatever options you want below.

```
infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
  map: map,
  content: '<br><a target="_blank" href="'+place.website+'">'+place.website+'</a>',
  shadowStyle: 1,
  padding: 8,
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(57,57,57)',
  borderRadius: 4,
  borderWidth: 5,
  borderColor: '#2c2c2c'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
  }
});
```

Comment: how I can implement that in my example?

Comment: Include the infobubble.js file included there and pass in the options you want. Or for an infobox, see the comment made above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522195/change-infowindows-with-infobox/18522259?noredirect=1#comment27238715_18522195

Comment: ok, I will include but is I then need to change infoWindow.setContent and similar code ???

Comment: added an example above

Comment: Should be noted that "Infobox" and "Infobubble" are two different plugins