# Google maps api : infowindow background transparent

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My website use google maps and display popup (InfoWindow) when clicking on markers.
I don't know why and since when, but actually the popup background is transparent.

Can anyone help me understand?

**UPDATE after good answer of Dr.Molle**

Wrong code :

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: '500px'}), mapsMarker, i;
```

Good code :

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: '500'}), mapsMarker, i;
```

Comment: Can you add code to your question that demonstrates the problem, not just linking to an external site.

Comment: try setting opacity of infobox to 1.

Comment: you have to define a background-color. may be style of infow-window gets affected by other defined classes. you could also use [infobubble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634991/styling-google-maps-infowindow) but nowadays there is a ton of different info-window libs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the issue seems to be the `maxWidth` - setting of the `InfoWindow`. The API expects a number,  but you provide a string `500px`. Set the `maxWidth`  to `500`