# Shortcode In Gmap Infowindow

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, shortcode

I am wondering how can I successfully implement shortcode inside a google maps infowindow? It just shows up as plain text and doesn't actually convert, is this even possible? If so, how do I go about making this a reality?

This is the code I am using:

```
var item = $('<div class="slider-item"></div>')
                .append('<div class="slider-item-image"><a class="fc-gmap-title-image"></a></div>')
                .append('<div class="slider-item-countdown">[rhc_countdown]</div>')
                .append('<div class="fc-start"></div>')
                .append('<div class="slider-item-title"><a class="fc-gmap-title-link"></a></div>')
            ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps are embeded in your page using an `iframe`. This isolates the map, and the InfoWindow, from the page that contains the map.

So, no, you can't use classes defined in your page to style an InfoWindow.

Take a look at this question for ways to style your InfoWindows: [Styling Google Maps InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634991/styling-google-maps-infowindow)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not trying to style it however. I'm simply just trying to add shortcode to it but it doesn't seem to be converting. Just displaying as plain text.