# How to change position of Marker Popup/Tooltip to Left or Right?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]

The marker display on TOP position. 
How can we display in Left Position or Right Position ?

This is my Code, Please check it.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initMap() {
    var locations = [
      ['Manly Beach', -33.800, 151.287, 'BMW-4', 'marker_blue.png'],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 'BMW-5', 'default_marker.png']
    ];
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: latLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map, labelContent: locations[i][3], labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
        labelClass: "labels", labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}, icon: locations[i][4]
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker1, i));
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by you "want to display Marker Popup In left or Right"?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the **[Google Maps Javascript API Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)**. Currently, there's no way you can change the Info Window's location. However, there are ways you can style/customize your info window. You can use **[InfoBubble](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-info-bubble/examples/example.html)**, **[5 ways to customize Google Maps InfoWindow](http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html)**.

You might want to check out this post **[Styling Google Maps InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634991/styling-google-maps-infowindow)**
.

You can file for a **Feature Request** at **[Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)**. Just provide sufficient details about this request.

> Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and
>   feature requests during product development. It is available outside
>   of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to
>   collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.

To learn more, you can check **[Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)**.

Hope it helps!