# how to styling google map infoWindow

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

i have a vue-google-map which need to display some content when clicked on the marker.
how can i set the style for the infoWindow? this is my code which called the id iw-container into the css sheets.

```
    this.infoWindow.position = location;
    this.infoWindow.template = '<div class="iw-container"><div 
      style="width:100%;">NAME OF PIN</div>'
      + '<div style="width:100%;">name and info</div></div>';
    this.infoWindow.open = true;
```

this is the css:

```
#iw-container {
  background-color:pink;
}
```

but there are nothing happen to the infoWindow.

i also has try to set the style straight into the content like this :

```
this.infoWindow.position = location;
this.infoWindow.template = '<div style="background-color:pink;"><div 
  style="width:100%;">NAME OF PIN</div>'
  + '<div style="width:100%;">name and info</div></div>';
this.infoWindow.open = true;
```

but the colour is not completely fulfilled the infoWindow. can anyone suggest what can i do or anything that i should change?

Comment: Did you see [this part of the documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#customize)?  And [this example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup) (to which it refers)?

Comment: @geocodezip , from this example, i think it can be like this way right. 
           `<gmap-info-window
              :options="{
                maxWidth: 300,
                pixelOffset: { width: 0, height: -35 },
                background: 'blue', //changing background-color
              }"
              :position="infoWindow.position"
              :opened="infoWindow.open"
              @closeclick="infoWindow.open=false"
            >`

but there is nothing happen. what is the best variable for the background color? i tried background and background-color & both not working

Comment: This was my example changing the infowindow background (and stem/arrow) to green: https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1oyertb2/1/

Comment: thank you, i'll take a look on it and need time to understand it because it quite hard for me to think how to applied this pure JS into vue.js stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling Google Maps InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634991/styling-google-maps-infowindow)

Answer (score 0):

In your code in css you use '#' for class selector use '.'

```
.iw-container {
  background-color:pink;
}
```

Comment: actually i have tried both class and id. but both are not working. in that my code example i forget to change it back

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code in my current project and working fine for me.

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: {lat: 72.231444,lng: 23.443423 }
});

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 var lat = 72.231444;
 var lng = 23.443423;
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: {lat, lng},
         map: map,
 });
 var infocontent = "<div class='map-box-content'>"+
                "<h4>name</h4>"+
                "<p>address</p>" +
                "</div>";

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
     infowindow.setContent(infocontent);
 });
```

css:

```
.map-box-content{
    width: 230px;
}
```

Comment: yes it worked but the background-color set for the infoWindow is not fully covered. it's only covered the <div> content and left white space at the outer layer